# Custom annotation for @Test methods to toggle features

Tags: junit, annotations, aop

I'd like to create a custom annotation for JUnit `@Test` methods that toggles features:

```
@Test
@UsingFeature("abc")
public void someTestMethod() { ... }
```

I created a corresponding annotation

```
public @interface UsingFeature {
    String value();
}
```

And an aspect

```
@Aspect
public class UsingFeatureAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(@mypackage.UsingFeature * * (..))")
    public void allAnnotatedMethods() { }

    @Before("allAnnotatedMethods()")
    public void switchFeatureOn() {
        // switch feature on
    }

    @Before
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "allAnnotatedMethods()", returning = "result")
    public void switchFeatureOff(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
        // switch feature off
    }

}
```

But my aspect functions are never called. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: JUnit itself doesn't evaluate aspects. Can you provide us, how you initialize this aspect (or aspect framework) in your test code?

Comment: Feature toggle libraries like [Togglz](https://github.com/togglz/togglz) provide custom rules (for JUnit 4) or extensions (for JUnit 5) to handle feature toggles in tests. Maybe this a way to look into.

Comment: I hoped that Spring would take care of the aspect handling. My `UsingFeatureAspect` is actually also annotated as `@Component`, and my test class has `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

Comment: Interesting idea with togglz. At first glance, looks like they use [their own JUnitRunner](https://github.com/togglz/togglz/blob/d4a887ec84748c837c2a1ed6007ff87c48480241/junit/src/main/java/org/togglz/junit/vary/FeatureVariations.java) to handle their custom annotations.